# Is it possible to get all possible sizes in a certain category?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, filter

We have a LOT of sizes in our database. This makes a size filter near impossible unless we narrow down the filter to the possible values found in the category the user is browsing.

Is it possible to return an array or list made from only the sizes that are available in the products of a certain category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get sizes that are available in the products of a certain category by this code:

```
$categoryId = 1;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('size', array('neq' => null));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH, 
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
));
$collection->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.is_in_stock=1',
    'left'
);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('gteq' => 1));
$collection->getSelect()->group('size');

$sizeCollection = array();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $sizeCollection[] = $product['size'];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($sizeCollection);
die;
```

Comment: Won't this load up all the products though? How will this be performance wise? Edit: Nevermind, just noticed you grouped by size. Thank you!

Comment: Going to try it asap and mark the answer correct. :)